# Map projected array from matplolib basemap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a rectangular array (360 x 180) that I want to project onto an orthographic projection. I can do this with basemap:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(180) - 90., np.arange(360) - 180.)
z = np.random.rand(360, 180)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
m = Basemap(projection='ortho', lon_0=0, lat_0=0.,
    resolution='l', ax=ax)
cs = m.contourf(x, y, z, 100, cmap=plt.cm.jet, latlon=True)
```

what I really want though is a 2d array (N x N) back that is the projected image so that I can do more calculations with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I have found a solution but it's very slow. Once I plot the array I can do

```
im = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
im = im.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,)).astype(np.float32)
```

to read the plot window back into an array im. If anyone has a way of doing this without having to actually do any plotting that would be great!